# Event receiver to invalidate cache in multiple WFE

Tags: c#, caching, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

When a list item event receiver is triggered in a multiple WFE farm, will it trigger in the other WFEs?

I currently don't have the resources to test this out myself and my search has given me nothing conclusive regarding this issue.

Background: I have a Settings list that is used to store configuration settings used throughout the application, this list is not accessible to normal users so RunWithElevatedPrivileges is used to read the items. A number of these items are accessed frequently and I was thinking of storing them in some form of a cache and add an item event receiver to invalidate the cache when modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint farm each user request can potentially be handled by different WFE server. It depends on load balancer's decision. Therefore each update can be handled by different WFE server and it does not matter if event receiver is fired on the same server or not.

You can use synchronous event receivers that are executed in the same thread as update operation. But remember that each update operation can be handled by different server.

The point is to use such case of cache that is accessible for all servers. No in memory cache will help you. You need cache persisted in e.g. SQL. Here are [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647588.aspx), [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558270(v=office.14).aspx) articles about caching in SharePoint.

Do remember that not all data can be cached as they are not thread safe. That means they can not be persisted. These are typically file handlers, TCP ports, ...

Comment: Thanks. I will probably redesign how we save our settings, and move the frequently accessed values to sql table.